# Yii2: How can I pass an array as parameter to a controller action?

Tags: arrays, url, parameters, controller, yii2

With the URL `http://localhost/site/myAction?a[]=value1&a[]=value2` I'm trying to pass an array to an action. The controller action looks like this:

```
class SiteController extends Controller {
    public function actionMyAction($a) {
        ...
    }
}
```

I get the error:

> exception 'yii\base\InvalidParamException' with message 'Variable
>   declaration not valid.'

Actually, I'd like to be able to pass a string or an array of strings to the action. The single string works fine but not the array. How can I solve it?

Answer (score 4):

Passing a string *and* an array with the same declared parameter is not possible as it seems. To pass an array the parameter has to be declared this way:

```
class SiteController extends Controller {
    public function actionMyAction(array $a) { // parameter must be an array now
        ...
    }
}
```

With this a single parameter in the URL needs to be wrapped into an array within the URL.

An alternative is to declare no parameter at all and fetch the values with [`Yii::$app->request->get()`](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-web-request.html#get()-detail):

```
class SiteController extends Controller {
    public function actionMyAction() {       // no parameter anymore
        $a = Yii::$app->request->get('a');   // $a can be an array or a string!
                                             // or null if no argument was passed.
    }
}
```

Now these URLs are valid:

```
http://localhost/site/myAction?a[]=value1&a[]=value2
http://localhost/site/myAction?a[]=value1
http://localhost/site/myAction?a=value1
http://localhost/site/myAction
```

Answer (score 1):

```
compareList=[{"model":"shine"},{"model":"yamaha-alba"}]
```

using json encode data you can pass multiple value.

Comment: You mean with `$.ajax()`? Question was about the controller action - if it accepts an array. Not how to send data.